# Setting a form's Record Source on Load event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was hoping to use one form that has 3 layouts, but change the data source as the form loads.  Here is the code that is called during OnLoad

```
Private Sub ShowInputLog(iLogType As Integer)

'Determines the Log Type Layout
'For data entry

     Select Case iLogType

        Case 1 '"MIPR"
            Me.Caption = "MIPR"
            Me.RecordSource = "tbl_MIPR"
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(0).Visible = True
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(0).Enabled = True
            Me.cmbPR_NUM.SetFocus
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(1).Visible = False
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(2).Visible = False
        Case 2 '"SPSPR"
            Me.RecordSource = "tbl_SPSPR"
            Me.Caption = "SPSPR"
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(0).Visible = False
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(1).Visible = True
            Me.cmbPR_Contr.SetFocus
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(2).Visible = False
        Case 3 '"WBS"
            Me.RecordSource = "tbl_WBS"
            Me.Caption = "WBS"
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(0).Visible = False
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(1).Visible = False
            Me.TabCodes.Pages(2).Visible = True
            Me.cmbWBS_Num.SetFocus
    End Select


End Sub
```

Will this work?  I was hoping to see the recordsource property with my table defined, but it remains blank.

Comment: BTW, Why don't check and see the results...?

Comment: Yes. I did check earlier and just wanted to confirm it works.  Turns out I had another routine that wasn't compiling properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work, but all tables should have displayed columns with the same names. If you have different names, create a query on each table, having identical field names, expected by the form. 
Such code runs on one of my Apps for 9 different queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work, but all tables should have displayed columns with the same names. If you have different names, create few subforms and change subform's `SourceObject` property on main form depending on iLogType